# How to see messages sent to Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have created the Google Cloud Messaging demo app as per the instructions at http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Everything seems to be working fine, but I do not receive the push notification after sending the notification. Is there any way to see messages that are sent/queued on the Google side? Similarly, is there a way to verify the message was actually sent to GoogleCloudMessaging?

Comment: check your web server, make sure it is sending msg with correct device id.

Comment: It looks like it may have been a matter of patience. About 20-25 minutes after sending the message, my client kicked in and started receiving the notifications. Which begs the question, how do I get the turn around time to be faster?

Comment: may be your client has low internet or no internet on the device.